# Как передать большой массив (на 5000000 байт) элементов в процедуру?

Tags: delphi

Как передать большой массив (на 5000000 байт) элементов в процедуру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нужно передавать указатель на этот массив, например:

```
type   MyArray = array [1..5000000] of Byte;
       PMyArray = ^MyArray;

procedure Proc(ar: PMyArray)
begin
    // код
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Передать массив по ссылке:

```
type   MyArray = array [1..5000000] of Byte;

procedure Proc(var ar: MyArray)
begin
    // код
end;
```

Comment: Развер MyArray будет ссылкой на массив? Почему?

Comment: Потому что **var** перед именем параметра указывает на то, что параметр будет передан в процедуру по ссылке. Передача по ссылке позволяет обойтись без указателей, где они совершенно не нужны.

Comment: @insolor некорректно. var перед параметром в процедуре означает несколько иное, а именно возможность изменить параметр/ссылку на него, в зависимости от типа.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, (спустя годы) возможно вы и правы, но мне сейчас не очень интересно разбираться в Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите передать статический массив в функцию или процедуру, вы обязаны предварительно его типизировать:

```
const
 ArSize = 50000;
type 
  MyAr = array[1..ArSize] of byte;

procedure MyProc(ar:MyAr);
```

Тогда как динамический массив не требует этого:

```
procedure MyProc(ar:array of byte);
```

А вот далее всё зависит от организации вашей программы. Во-первых, в зависимости от размера массива, Delphi передаёт его либо в стеке, либо как указатель на массив. При этом в стеке данные передаются только в том случае, если влезают в стандартный размер регистра (EAX для 32-бит, RAX для 64-бит), то есть для 32-битных программ это максимум array[1..4] of byte, для 64-битных - в 2 раза больше. В остальных случаях массив передаётся в виде указателя на него.

Важно помнить, что в отличие от динамических массивов и других сложных структур, для обычных массивов Delphi несёт совместимость с TurboPascal, а именно: указатель var перед переменной вернёт изменения, произведенные внутри процедуры/функции, то есть:

```
type 
  MyAr = array[1..ArSize] of byte;

procedure Proc1(ar:MyAr);
begin
  ar[1]:=5;
end;

procedure Proc2(var ar:MyAr);
begin
  ar[1]:=5;
end;

var
  a:MyAr;

begin
 a[1]:=1;
 Proc1(a); // без изменений
 Proc2(a); // a[1] будет равно 5
end.
```

То есть, если вам необходимо вносить изменения в передаваемый массив, указывайте **var** (альтернатива: **out**) внутри определения функции, иначе - не нужно.

В случае динамических массивов и иных сложных структур указание **var** будет влиять лишь на возможность изменения указателя на структуру, но никак не на изменение структуры, как таковой. Однако, для облегчения читаемости кода рекомендуется указывать **var** даже в этих случаях (я предпочитаю **out**), явно указывая на то, что функция **будет изменять** переданные данные.